# Variable whitepsace in negative lookbehind?

Tags: java, regex

How can I match `x`, when not preceeded by `=`, regardless of possible whitespace between `=` and `x`?

Match:

```
= abc x
```

Do not match:

```
abc =      x
```

This regex 
`(?<!=)\bx\b` works if there is not whitespace between `=` and `x`, but cant be modified to account for the whitespace because the lookbehind assertion cannot be variable length.

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: @anubhava java regex

Comment: [For PCRE `=\h*x(*SKIP)(*F)|x` works](https://regex101.com/r/P1akqx/1)

Comment: Or you can make the spaces optional:  `(?<=)(\s{0,3})\bx\b`

Comment: [For Java you can use: `^(?!.*=\h*x).*x`](https://regex101.com/r/P1akqx/2/)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad that works, specifying a range of allowed spaces

Comment: You may use [`"(?<!=\\s{0,1000})\\bx\\b"`](https://ideone.com/73uQaE) if there cannot be more than 1K whitespaces before `x`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh, i thought that was what cybernetic.nomad was suggesting, to specify 0-3 spaces... i guess i dont undersand their suggestion

Comment: The point is that Java regex engine supports "dynamic" length lookbehind, it is called a "constrained width lookbehind".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Java you can use a negative lookahead since Java doesn't support dynamic length lookbehind assertions:

```
^(?!.*=\h*x).*x
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P1akqx/2/)

- `^`: Start
- `(?!.*=\h*x)`: Assert that we don't have `=` followed by 0 or more spaces and `x` ahead of us
- `.*x`: Match `x` anywhere in the string